# Convert `&T` into newtype `&N`

Tags: rust

I have a type `T` (`T` implements `Clone` but not `Copy`) and a newtype that is declared as `struct N(T)`. Given a reference `&T`, how can I wrap it into an `&N` without cloning the `&T` to get an owned `T` first?

Comment: Might be relevant: https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/bkqdvk/is_there_a_way_to_create_a_reference_to_a_trivial/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without external crates, this isn't possible without `unsafe`.

However, I do recommend using the [`ref-cast`](https://github.com/dtolnay/ref-cast) crate.
It's a crate published by `dtolnay`, the author of some of the biggest Rust crates, to provide safe abstractions for working around this very problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because `N` is a [single field struct](https://rust-lang.github.io/unsafe-code-guidelines/layout/structs-and-tuples.html#single-field-structs) you can transmute the reference:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct N<T>(T);
impl<T> N<T> {
    fn from_ref(v: &T) -> &Self {
        unsafe { std::mem::transmute(v) }
    }
}
```

But it's essential to do so in a function to let the compiler trace the borrow.

Disclaimer: Technically this is not guaranteed without `#[repr(transparent)]`

Comment: This is only safe if the newtype struct in question is marked [`#[repr(transparent)]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/other-reprs.html#reprtransparent).

Comment: That's a common misconception, the source I linked are official guidelines and as you'll see it doesn't require the `#[repr]`

Comment: @cafce25 What's the point of `#[repr(transparent)]` then? Why does it exist?

Comment: @Finomnis: The page linked in the answer and [RFC 1758](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1758-repr-transparent.md#summary) suggest that it’s only about FFI. Definitely not a comfortable amount of documentation though :/

Comment: @Finomnis `#[repr(transparent)]` is required when you want to pass a `struct N { a: c_int }` to a FFI function taking a `c_int` as in the C ABI a struct containing one field and a value of the same type are passed differently.

Comment: @cafce25 The Rust Reference pretty clearly states regarding the [default representation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#the-default-representation) that "the only data layout guarantees made by this representation are those required for soundness" (and also explicitly lists out its guarantees, none of which relate to single field structs). The Unsafe Code Guidelines reference self-describes as a "work-in-progress" "guide" that is "mostly a recommendation", so I think it's clear that it's non-authoritative, especially when directly contradicted by the reference itself.

Comment: The point of `repr(transparent)` is to ensure layout/ABI of the outer struct is the same as of the single field, this is exactly what we need here. FFI is just another application of `repr(transparent)`.

Comment: @cafce25 The source you linked is explicitly non-normative (and so is the reference, but the reference is still more reliable)).

Comment: Also, prefer pointer casting to `transmute()`.